# Fake Experience Dilemma

Tags: resume, career-development

I graduated from a US university in 2012 as a fresher and took up unpaid internships/jobs for mostly an year until I joined a consultancy in 2013. The consultancy put 7 years of fake experience on my resume and I was able to secure a contract job with one of their MNC clients. I worked for close to 8 months here before I became overwhelmed by the guilt and chose to return to India. Since most of my unpaid jobs and internships were undocumented, I asked the consultancy to issue me an offer letter stating I joined them soon after my graduation. The consultancy issued me the relevant documents I asked for. I found a job in India soon after my return and have been working since. **Here is what my profile looks like now.**

- 2012-2013: Employed by the consultancy (have the offer letter and
  relieve letter but no payslips since did not actually work with any clients).
- 2013-2014: Was with the consultancy (actually worked with their
  clients and have payslips).
- 2014-2016: Indian employer 1 (found the job here basis the above
  experience).
- 2016 onward: Indian employer 2 (found the job here basis the above
  experience).

**Problems:**

- A. Still have little built of guilt about the one year (2012-13) I did not
  work, but showing that I worked with clients
  following:
- My US client may find out that I did not actually have 7 years of experience when I joined them.
- Don't want to reveal my consultancy name, hence don't know what to mention for 2012-2013.
- If I remove my 12-13 experience, my Indian employers may find out I did not actually work during that time.

How do I legitimise my current profile. Please help. I am determined to come clean.

Comment: I'm confused, what is preventing you from simply using an accurate resume going forward?

Comment: @DavidK: Two issues mainly, 1. What do I show for 2012-2013? That I simply sat idle? 2. I want to create a social profile, please see the dilemma points I mentioned. If I create an accurate resume, what if my current employer and past employers see?

Comment: Your former employers have no sway over you. Did you apply to your current employer with your faked experience, after already having left one job because you felt guilty about lying about your experience?

Comment: The issue is with the point 2012-2013 above, where I did not work on any client projects, but did mention while applying for my current job. Regarding your point of former employers having no sway, won't they contact my current team on social media to point out issues?

Comment: It's unclear why you need to create a fake resume. Why do you have to lie about it? It would make more sense to simply say, "I didn't work between 2012-13 because I was in school" or whatever.

Comment: Also, reading it again, I am not understanding why consulting agency lied for you with fake 7 years of experience. Are you saying the job between 2012-13 is with the agency who lied for you to get a job in the US? Needless to say, this question sounds shady and questionable.

Comment: So were you a part of the consultancy group in 2012-2013 or not? Your first paragraph says you didn't join until 2013, but your bullets say you were employed but not working.

Comment: Unpaid internships are work, just work for free. If you gained valuable experience doing that, just list the internships as internships.

Comment: @Dan If you're aware, there are these firms in US which fabricate your resume and let you land a job with one of their clients. I am saying I removed the 7 years fake experience. When they issued me the offer letter in 2013, I asked them to mention in the letter that I joined them in 2012.

Comment: @DavidK When they issued me the offer letter in 2013, I asked them to mention in the letter that I joined them in 2012.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions in the comments:

> What do I show for 2012-2013? That I simply sat idle?

You write what you actually did. You say you "took up unpaid internships/jobs for mostly an year until I joined a consultancy in 2013", so include those. If you sat idle, then you don't write anything and be ready to explain why you didn't have a job (*e.g. applying but not landing anything? taking time off to travel? spending time with family/friends before moving away?*)

Even though you have a letter from the consultancy that says you started in 2012, *that is a lie.* Do **not** include it.

> If I create an accurate resume, what if my current employer and past employers see?

Your past employers should have no sway over you. It is extremely unlikely that they would contact your current workplace. I doubt your current employer will look you up, but if they do see your profile and don't like what they see, then frankly, you suck it up and deal with the consequences. *You* are the one who decided to lie on your resume. If you want to come clean, that means also dealing with the fallout.

You also have the option of coming clean to your employer before they discover this on their own. It's not clear to me why (or even if) you lied to your latest employer at all, as you have 3 years of legitimate job experience to leverage. Confessing has the potential to make you look bad for something they might never realize though, so it is a risk. Personally, I would try to forget about it and make sure that everything is accurate when you start looking for your next job.