# I faked experience certificate to my new employer

Tags: software-industry, work-experience

2 years ago I got this current job as a software developer in a very reputable company. I've been performing very well since the day I joined ,and last year i scored 86.5 out of 100 in an performance review. Also I am now considered as one of the best programmers.

Years ago, I and two other friends started a start-up company and I was the CTO, exactly a year later I resigned due to some business level conflicts we couldn't resolve. They never gave me an experience certificate and now the company is no longer in the software developing business, they do digital marketing things.

After resignation, I got a job at an outsourcing company by cracking the interview with a higher score.

A year later I resigned and got this current job, again scoring highest points at the interview series including the technical interview.

Since I could not get an experience certificate from my first company, I created one and gave it to my current company and the previous one. Since I was the CTO at the first company and I did lots of hard work I thought I deserved it.

The HR department relocated to new office premises and they misplaced documents of a few employees during the process. They never asked me to resubmit them until now.

There is a promotion waiting and HR asked me to submit those documents to complete the employee profile so they can proceed with the promotion thing (they consider total years of experience for this).

During the resubmission of docs, will I get caught with the fake experience certificate?

What can I do to correct this error?

**EDIT**
i do have company registration with my name on it as a director

Comment: You could say that already sent all the information you had, and give HR a contact number/mail so they could check that you worked there, there is no reason to cross the previous information.

Comment: So ate you saying they lost the original and only copy? Then they have to accept that you had one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fake Experience Dilemma](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/103938/fake-experience-dilemma)

Comment: @solar mike i never gave them original copy of the fake certificate, they lost the copy of it

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: You say to HR "What experience certificate? I was a founder and CTO. Here is the documentation."

Comment: Is this a [tag:relieving-letter] question?

Answer (score 31):

I think being both a founder and sitting in the C-suite of a company gives you the right to give yourself a reference. It isn't fake, so stop using that word.

Comment: however, i have company registration with my name on it as a director

Comment: @rockey That just reinforces my point that your reference isn't a fake.

Comment: @rockey If you are a Director at startup, it doesn`t mean that you do not do any other work. As founder / owner you do what yu do best - it may be business development, software development, HR or any other thing from plethora that every business need to do. And i agree with user1666620 - its not fake, so you should not see it as fake

Comment: @user1666620 OP doesn't say where they work. However, in countries where something like an "experience certificate" is common, that's really not the same as a reference in, e.g., the US. You can't give yourself an "experience certificate". You also don't need to if you are a founder (and co-owner). OP should have just submitted documentation about their actual position.